# angular 4 iterate over objects of objects for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to iterate over objects of object

Here is response json I will get

```
    { 
     "123445": {
      "displayName": "abcd",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "e7363730-552d-4943-a3b8-082db653fc16",
          "name": "xyz",
          "displayName": "xyd",
          "price": "75",
          "quntity": "100"
        },
        {
          "id": "302fda08-502d-4f5a-98b8-cbca34f8e186",
          "name": "pqr",
          "displayName": "pqr",
          "price": "60",
          "quntity": "100"
        }

      ]
    }
}
```

Here is what am trying

```
<div *ngFor="let key of generateKeys(products | async)">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products[key].items | async">{{ product | json}}</div>
</div>
```

and here is funtion which will return keys from products object

```
  generateKeys(obj) {
    return obj ? Object.keys(obj) : null
  }
```

But while rendering HTML template it is giving err that

```
Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Am I missing something, please suggest.

Comment: Your **productsList** is an object now not an array if you want an array make: `productsList = [{object1},{object2},{and so on}]`

Comment: @Swoox, he used `Object.keys` which returns an array :)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Will return an array of object keys but still productsList is an object you can't *ngFor on it.

Comment: @Swoox, no. `generateKeys` returns an array then he iterate `products[key]`.items which is an array.

Comment: @Swoox yes I have use Object.keys to get keys. For better naming I have change variable name productList to products

Comment: @Sam, try to declare function using `get` keyword. `get generateKeys(obj) {
    return obj ? Object.keys(obj) : null
  }`

Comment: @Sam Can you make a log of the keys it's returning?

Comment: @Swoox yes keys are returning as expected

Comment: @Sam so it's **123445** or a string? My guess is you use `"123445": {` the object return a key without quotes. Try changing it in: `123445: {` .

Comment: @Swoox It is returning as the same data type.Yes, it is returning the string. I have also tried with key as a string

Comment: @Sam, there is no need for `async` here.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I am fetching product data from a server so I have use async pipe

Comment: @Sam, yes, but is no need. It works as well without it.`Angular` attach a `watch` object to see when data is changed.

Comment: @sam try to `this.products = JSON.parse(this.products)` when you fetching it.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Without async it is not rendering anything.

Comment: @Swoox still not working

Comment: @Sam what it say is that `products[key]` not exist try to comment out the second loop. And do `{{products[key]}}` in your first **ngFor**

Comment: @Sam, I provide an example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/U5xbZ69pasFrToirvHMf?p=preview

Comment: @Sam, have a look now.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai this is own made object plz read what he say he's fetching data from a service that's why he need Async....

Comment: @Swoox, no. There is no need to `async`. `async` is specially used when you're using `object.name` and `object` is undefined firstly. Using `async` just help to do display error when trying to access name property. In this case with *ngFor there is no need.

Comment: Move to chat?...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo your code is not working for me. As I am using produts as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

Comment: "not working" isnt really helpful, comment on the given answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding you can try this

template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="products | async as products">
    <div *ngFor="let key of generateKeys(products)">
        <span>{{key}}</span>
        <div *ngFor="let product of getProducts(products,key)">
            <span>{{product.id}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

the function generateKeys will returns keys from object

```
 generateKeys(obj) {
    return obj ? Object.keys(obj) : null
  }
```

and function getProducts will return items from products

```
 getProducts(productsList, key: string) {
    return key ? productsList[key].items : null
  }
```

hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Component({...})
export class FooComponent{
 products$: Observable<{[id:string]:any}>;

 constructor(private _fooService: FooService){
   this.products$ = _fooService.getProducts().share(); //set observable
 }

  get keys$(){
    return this.products$
    .map(map => Object.keys(map));
  }

  getProducts$(key:string){
    // TODO check key existence
    return this.products$
     .map(map => map[key])
     .map(obj => obj.items || [])
  }
}

<div *ngFor="let key of keys$ | async">
    <div *ngFor="let product of getProducts$(key) | async">{{ product | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Another, less rjxs oriented approach, would be:

```
@Component({...})
export class FooComponent{
 products$: Observable<{[id:string]:any}>;

 constructor(private _fooService: FooService){
   this.products$ = _fooService.getProducts(); //set observable
 }

  getKeys(map: any): string[]{
    let result = [];
    if(map){
      result = Object.keys(map); 
    }
    return result;
  }

  getProducts(key:string,map: any): any[] {
    let result [];
    if(map & map[key]){
     result = map[key];
    }
    return result;
  }
}

<ng-container *ngIf="products$| async as products">
  <div *ngFor="let key of getKeys(products)">
    <div *ngFor="let product of getProducts(key,products)">{{ product | json}}
    </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```